# Get Levenshtein Distance

Tags: performance, strings, powershell, edit-distance

Logic based of [this site](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/Pruhs/Spring2006/assignments/editdistance/Levenshtein%20Distance.htm) which had a VB example I used as a base.

```
function Get-LevenshteinDistance{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$CompareString,
        [string]$DifferenceString
    )

    # Collect the string lengths
    $compareStringLength = $CompareString.Length
    $differenceStringLength = $DifferenceString.Length
    Write-Verbose "Comparision String: '$CompareString' with length '$compareStringLength'"
    Write-Verbose "Difference String: '$DifferenceString' with length '$differenceStringLength'"

    # If either of the strings are empty the LD is known and we can stop
    if($compareStringLength -eq 0){return $differenceStringLength}
    if($differenceStringLength -eq 0){return $compareStringLength}

    # Build the comparison matrix and populate the first column and first row. 
    $comparisonMatrix = New-Object 'object[,]'  ($differenceStringLength+1),($compareStringLength+1)

    # Populate the first row
    for($index=0; $index -le $compareStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[0,$index]=$index
    }

    # Populate the first column
    for($index=0; $index -le $differenceStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[$index,0]=$index
    }

    # Calculate the Levenshtein distance by working through each position in the matrix. 
    # Working the columns
    for($columnIndex=1; $columnIndex -le $compareStringLength; $columnIndex++){
        # Cycle each character in the list
        $compareCharacter = $compareString[$columnIndex-1]

        # Working the rows
        for($rowIndex=1; $rowIndex -le $differenceStringLength; $rowIndex++){
            # Cycle each character in the list
            $differenceCharacter = $differenceString[$rowIndex-1]

            Write-Verbose "Matrix location: [$rowIndex, $columnIndex]"
            Write-Verbose "Compare character: $compareCharacter - Difference character: $differenceCharacter"
            # Calculate the cost
            $cost=if($compareCharacter -eq $differenceCharacter){0}else{1}
            Write-Verbose "Cost: $cost"

            # The cell immediately above plus 1
            $cellAbove = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1
            Write-Verbose "Cell Above: [$($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1 = $cellAbove"

            # The cell immediately to the left plus 1
            $cellLeft =  $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,($columnIndex-1)] + 1
            Write-Verbose "Cell Left: [$rowIndex,$($columnIndex-1)] + 1 = $cellLeft"

            # The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost
            $cellUpperLeft = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1),($columnIndex-1)] + $cost
            Write-Verbose "Cell Upper Left: [$($rowIndex-1),$($columnIndex-1)] + cost($cost) = $cellUpperLeft"

            # Select minumum of the of the last 3 cells calculations and assign it to the current matrix position.
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = $cellAbove,$cellLeft,$cellUpperLeft | Measure-Object -Minimum | select -ExpandProperty Minimum
        }
    }
    # The cacluated LD will now be in the bottom right of the matrix.
    return $comparisonMatrix[$differenceStringLength,$compareStringLength]
}
```

Was working on a PPCG question where I had to roll my own LD calculator. Since I saw future value in this I made a more professional looking version. Since it is iterating over every character in a string for every other character in the other string it really starts to show its performance issues when they start to get over 50 chars in size.

The model it uses supports deletions, insertions and substitutions. If I wanted to change the weight of substitutions I suppose I would need to edit this line and support a parameter for it?

```
$cost=if($compareCharacter -eq $differenceCharacter){0}else{1}
```

Never really played with multidimensional arrays before and I am not sure how I could improve on this. I know there are a few things I could do to make the code more brief and still functional however I opted for this solution as I liked the improved readability.

Comment: `itterating` should probably be `iterating`

Comment: @yuri probably :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my development series (in parentheses: approx fast ratio compared with the previous, tested using strings cca 100 characters in size, see the comparison table below):

- `Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig`  (= `1×`, for comparison): the original function body (Copy&Paste);
- `Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig+` (> `3×`, still insufficient): removed all time-expensive  `Write-Verbose` output;
- `Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry1`  (> `50×`, a substantial improvement): time-expensive pipeline to `Measure-Object` replaced by `[math]::Min(n,m)` static method (see [.NET system.math class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=netframework-4.7.2)). The following are only minor advancement steps:
- `Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry2`  (~ `1×`..`2×`): slight algorithm renovation:

  - instead calculating the cost (`$cost` variable): if compared characters are equal then computing and comparing values `$cellAbove`, `$cellLeft` and `$cellUpperLeft` is useless as we already *know* the necessary value;
  - added: if strings are equal the LD is known (zero) and we can stop;
- `Get-LevenshteinDistance`      (~ `2×`): PoSH array implementation: instead  of *two-dimensional* comparison matrix used a *rectangular [jagged](http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/csharp3/jagged_arrays.html)* array.

**Comparison table:** `.\CR\164518test.ps1 | Format-Table -AutoSize`

```
cmdlet                       similarity runtime (ms) lengths  LD
------                       ---------- ------------ -------  --
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig  equal       6829.1053   106 106   0
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig+ equal       2010.4538   106 106   0
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry1  equal         35.8835   106 106   0
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry2  equal           .1795   106 106   0
Get-LevenshteinDistance      equal           .1539   106 106   0
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig  stochastic  6556.4117   106 102  79
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig+ stochastic  1932.6051   106 102  79
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry1  stochastic    33.9023   106 102  79
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry2  stochastic    28.3165   106 102  79
Get-LevenshteinDistance      stochastic    13.4852   106 102  79
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig  similar     6640.5884   106 102   4
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig+ similar     2023.8179   106 102   4
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry1  similar       31.5843   106 102   4
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry2  similar       14.9307   106 102   4
Get-LevenshteinDistance      similar        8.4234   106 102   4
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig  different   6613.5267   106 102 106
Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig+ different   1943.7630   106 102 106
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry1  different     35.1824   106 102 106
Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry2  different     27.1371   106 102 106
Get-LevenshteinDistance      different     13.8924   106 102 106
```

Column explanation:

- `cmdlet`       - function name
- `similarity`   - in brief "*like*" similarity of input strings
- `runtime (ms)` - `TotalMilliseconds`
- `lengths`      - lengths of input strings, space delimited
- `LD`           - the Levenshtein Distance of input strings

**Comparison script** `164518test.ps1`:

```
Function TestLD {
    param ([string]$Similarity = '')

    $aux = 0
    Write-Progress -Activity "LD info ($Similarity strings)" `
         -CurrentOperation 'Start' -PercentComplete $aux
    $cmdletTails = 'Orig','Orig+','Try1','Try2',''
    foreach ( $cmdletTail in $cmdletTails ) {
        $cmdlet = "Get-LevenshteinDistance$cmdletTail"
        $scriptBlock = { $LevenshteinDistance = & $cmdlet `
                -CompareString $strC -DifferenceString $strD }
        $TimeSpan = Measure-Command -Expression $scriptBlock
        $aux += [int](100 / $cmdletTails.Count)
        Write-Progress -Activity "LD info ($Similarity strings)" `
             -CurrentOperation $cmdlet -PercentComplete $aux
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'cmdlet'     = $cmdlet
            'similarity' = $Similarity
            'runtime (ms)'   = $($TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds.
                               ToString('#####.###0',$cultureinfo).
                                   PadLeft(10))
            'lengths'    = "$($strC.Length) $($strD.Length)"
            'LD'         = $LevenshteinDistance
        }
    }
}


. D:\PShell\CR\164518.ps1                        # reload the functions
$cultureinfo = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture   # my one is different
$strC='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum placerat leo ut turpis viverra lacinia'
$strD=$strC
TestLD -Similarity 'equal'
$strD='Cras efficitur nec orci et posuere. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque blandit auctor purus id facilisis est'
TestLD -Similarity 'stochastic'
$strC='a' * $strC.Length
$strD='a' * $strD.Length
TestLD -Similarity 'similar'
$strD='x' * $strD.Length
TestLD -Similarity 'different'
```

**The main script `164518.ps1`** (functions are defined here in the reverse order):

```
function Get-LevenshteinDistance{
    param(
        [string]$CompareString,
        [string]$DifferenceString
    )

    # Collect the string lengths
    $compareStringLength    = $CompareString.Length
    $differenceStringLength = $DifferenceString.Length

    # If either of the strings are empty the LD is known and we can stop
    if($compareStringLength -eq 0){return $differenceStringLength}
    if($differenceStringLength -eq 0){return $compareStringLength}
    # If strings are equal the LD is known and we can stop
    if ($CompareString -ceq $DifferenceString) { return 0 }

    # Build the comparison matrix as a (rectangular) jagged array
  # $comparisonMatrix = New-Object 'object[]' ($differenceStringLength+1)
    $comparisonMatrix = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([System.Object], ($differenceStringLength+1))
    for($index=0; $index -le $differenceStringLength; $index++){
        # Create row
      # $comparisonMatrix[$index]=New-Object 'object[]'  ($compareStringLength+1)
        $comparisonMatrix[$index]=[System.Array]::CreateInstance([System.Object], ($compareStringLength+1))
        # Populate the first column
        $comparisonMatrix[$index][0]=$index
    }
    # Populate the first row
    for($index=0; $index -le $compareStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[0][$index]=$index
    }

    # Calculate the Levenshtein distance by working through each position in the matrix. 
    # Working the columns
    for($columnIndex=1; $columnIndex -le $compareStringLength; $columnIndex++){
        # Cycle each character in the list
        $compareCharacter = $compareString[$columnIndex-1] # multiple use => to a variable

        # Working the rows
        for($rowIndex=1; $rowIndex -le $differenceStringLength; $rowIndex++){
            # Cycle each character in the list (a variable for the only use)
          # $differenceCharacter = $differenceString[$rowIndex-1] # the only use

            # Calculate the cost 
          if($compareCharacter -ceq $differenceString[$rowIndex-1]){
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex -1)][($columnIndex -1)]
          } else {
          # $cost = 1           # unneeded variable for the only use
            # The cell immediately above plus 1
            $cellAbove = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1)][$columnIndex] + 1

            # The cell immediately to the left plus 1
            $cellLeft =  $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex][($columnIndex-1)] + 1

          # # The cell diagonally above and to the left             plus the cost ↓ 
            $cellUpperLeft = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1)][($columnIndex-1)] + 1

            # Select minumum of the of the last 3 cells calculations and assign it to the current matrix position.
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = [math]::Min([math]::Min($cellAbove,$cellLeft),$cellUpperLeft)
          }
        }
    }
    # The cacluated LD will now be in the bottom right of the matrix.
    return $comparisonMatrix[$differenceStringLength][$compareStringLength]
}

function Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry2{
    param(
        [string]$CompareString,
        [string]$DifferenceString
    )

    # Collect the string lengths
    $compareStringLength    = $CompareString.Length
    $differenceStringLength = $DifferenceString.Length

    # If either of the strings are empty the LD is known and we can stop
    if($compareStringLength -eq 0){return $differenceStringLength}
    if($differenceStringLength -eq 0){return $compareStringLength}
    # If strings are equal the LD is known and we can stop
    if ($CompareString -ceq $DifferenceString) { return 0 }
    # Build the comparison matrix and populate the first column and first row. 
    $comparisonMatrix = New-Object 'object[,]' ($differenceStringLength+1),($compareStringLength+1)
  # $comparisonMatrix = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([System.Object], ($differenceStringLength+1),($compareStringLength+1))
    # Populate the first row
    for($index=0; $index -le $compareStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[0,$index]=$index
    }
    # Populate the first column
    for($index=0; $index -le $differenceStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[$index,0]=$index
    }

    # Calculate the Levenshtein distance by working through each position in the matrix. 
    # Working the columns
    for($columnIndex=1; $columnIndex -le $compareStringLength; $columnIndex++){
        # Cycle each character in the list
        $compareCharacter = $compareString[$columnIndex-1]

        # Working the rows
        for($rowIndex=1; $rowIndex -le $differenceStringLength; $rowIndex++){
            # Cycle each character in the list
            $differenceCharacter = $differenceString[$rowIndex-1]

            # Calculate the cost
          if($compareCharacter -ceq $differenceCharacter){
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex -1),($columnIndex -1)]
          } else {
            $cost = 1    # a variable for the only use? Useless!

            # The cell immediately above plus 1
            $cellAbove = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1

            # The cell immediately to the left plus 1
            $cellLeft =  $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,($columnIndex-1)] + 1

            # The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost
            $cellUpperLeft = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1),($columnIndex-1)] + $cost

            # Select minumum of the of the last 3 cells calculations and assign it to the current matrix position.
          # $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = $cellAbove,$cellLeft,$cellUpperLeft | Measure-Object -Minimum | select -ExpandProperty Minimum
          # $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = ($cellAbove,$cellLeft,$cellUpperLeft | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = [math]::Min([math]::Min($cellAbove,$cellLeft),$cellUpperLeft)
          }
        }
    }
    # The cacluated LD will now be in the bottom right of the matrix.
    return $comparisonMatrix[$differenceStringLength,$compareStringLength]
}

function Get-LevenshteinDistanceTry1{
    #[cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$CompareString,
        [string]$DifferenceString
    )

    # Collect the string lengths
    $compareStringLength = $CompareString.Length
    $differenceStringLength = $DifferenceString.Length
    ##Write-Verbose "Comparision String: '$CompareString' with length '$compareStringLength'"
    ##Write-Verbose "Difference String: '$DifferenceString' with length '$differenceStringLength'"

    # If either of the strings are empty the LD is known and we can stop
    if($compareStringLength -eq 0){return $differenceStringLength}
    if($differenceStringLength -eq 0){return $compareStringLength}

    # Build the comparison matrix and populate the first column and first row. 
    $comparisonMatrix = New-Object 'object[,]'  ($differenceStringLength+1),($compareStringLength+1)

    # Populate the first row
    for($index=0; $index -le $compareStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[0,$index]=$index
    }

    # Populate the first column
    for($index=0; $index -le $differenceStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[$index,0]=$index
    }

    # Calculate the Levenshtein distance by working through each position in the matrix. 
    # Working the columns
    for($columnIndex=1; $columnIndex -le $compareStringLength; $columnIndex++){
        # Cycle each character in the list
        $compareCharacter = $compareString[$columnIndex-1]

        # Working the rows
        for($rowIndex=1; $rowIndex -le $differenceStringLength; $rowIndex++){
            # Cycle each character in the list
            $differenceCharacter = $differenceString[$rowIndex-1]

            ##Write-Verbose "Matrix location: [$rowIndex, $columnIndex]"
            ##Write-Verbose "Compare character: $compareCharacter - Difference character: $differenceCharacter"
            # Calculate the cost
            $cost=if($compareCharacter -ceq $differenceCharacter){0}else{1}
            ##Write-Verbose "Cost: $cost"

            # The cell immediately above plus 1
            $cellAbove = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1
            ##Write-Verbose "Cell Above: [$($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1 = $cellAbove"

            # The cell immediately to the left plus 1
            $cellLeft =  $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,($columnIndex-1)] + 1
            ##Write-Verbose "Cell Left: [$rowIndex,$($columnIndex-1)] + 1 = $cellLeft"

            # The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost
            $cellUpperLeft = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1),($columnIndex-1)] + $cost
            ##Write-Verbose "Cell Upper Left: [$($rowIndex-1),$($columnIndex-1)] + cost($cost) = $cellUpperLeft"

            # Select minumum of the of the last 3 cells calculations and assign it to the current matrix position.
          # $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = $cellAbove,$cellLeft,$cellUpperLeft | Measure-Object -Minimum | select -ExpandProperty Minimum
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = [math]::Min([math]::Min($cellAbove,$cellLeft),$cellUpperLeft)
        }
    }
    # The cacluated LD will now be in the bottom right of the matrix.
    return $comparisonMatrix[$differenceStringLength,$compareStringLength]
}

function Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig+{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$CompareString,
        [string]$DifferenceString
    )

    # Collect the string lengths
    $compareStringLength = $CompareString.Length
    $differenceStringLength = $DifferenceString.Length
    ##Write-Verbose "Comparision String: '$CompareString' with length '$compareStringLength'"
    ##Write-Verbose "Difference String: '$DifferenceString' with length '$differenceStringLength'"

    # If either of the strings are empty the LD is known and we can stop
    if($compareStringLength -eq 0){return $differenceStringLength}
    if($differenceStringLength -eq 0){return $compareStringLength}

    # Build the comparison matrix and populate the first column and first row. 
    $comparisonMatrix = New-Object 'object[,]'  ($differenceStringLength+1),($compareStringLength+1)

    # Populate the first row
    for($index=0; $index -le $compareStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[0,$index]=$index
    }

    # Populate the first column
    for($index=0; $index -le $differenceStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[$index,0]=$index
    }

    # Calculate the Levenshtein distance by working through each position in the matrix. 
    # Working the columns
    for($columnIndex=1; $columnIndex -le $compareStringLength; $columnIndex++){
        # Cycle each character in the list
        $compareCharacter = $compareString[$columnIndex-1]

        # Working the rows
        for($rowIndex=1; $rowIndex -le $differenceStringLength; $rowIndex++){
            # Cycle each character in the list
            $differenceCharacter = $differenceString[$rowIndex-1]

            ##Write-Verbose "Matrix location: [$rowIndex, $columnIndex]"
            ##Write-Verbose "Compare character: $compareCharacter - Difference character: $differenceCharacter"
            # Calculate the cost
            $cost=if($compareCharacter -ceq $differenceCharacter){0}else{1}
            ##Write-Verbose "Cost: $cost"

            # The cell immediately above plus 1
            $cellAbove = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1
            ##Write-Verbose "Cell Above: [$($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1 = $cellAbove"

            # The cell immediately to the left plus 1
            $cellLeft =  $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,($columnIndex-1)] + 1
            ##Write-Verbose "Cell Left: [$rowIndex,$($columnIndex-1)] + 1 = $cellLeft"

            # The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost
            $cellUpperLeft = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1),($columnIndex-1)] + $cost
            ##Write-Verbose "Cell Upper Left: [$($rowIndex-1),$($columnIndex-1)] + cost($cost) = $cellUpperLeft"

            # Select minumum of the of the last 3 cells calculations and assign it to the current matrix position.
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = $cellAbove,$cellLeft,$cellUpperLeft | Measure-Object -Minimum | select -ExpandProperty Minimum
        }
    }
    # The cacluated LD will now be in the bottom right of the matrix.
    return $comparisonMatrix[$differenceStringLength,$compareStringLength]
}

function Get-LevenshteinDistanceOrig{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string]$CompareString,
        [string]$DifferenceString
    )

    # Collect the string lengths
    $compareStringLength = $CompareString.Length
    $differenceStringLength = $DifferenceString.Length
    Write-Verbose "Comparision String: '$CompareString' with length '$compareStringLength'"
    Write-Verbose "Difference String: '$DifferenceString' with length '$differenceStringLength'"

    # If either of the strings are empty the LD is known and we can stop
    if($compareStringLength -eq 0){return $differenceStringLength}
    if($differenceStringLength -eq 0){return $compareStringLength}

    # Build the comparison matrix and populate the first column and first row. 
    $comparisonMatrix = New-Object 'object[,]'  ($differenceStringLength+1),($compareStringLength+1)

    # Populate the first row
    for($index=0; $index -le $compareStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[0,$index]=$index
    }

    # Populate the first column
    for($index=0; $index -le $differenceStringLength; $index++){
        $comparisonMatrix[$index,0]=$index
    }

    # Calculate the Levenshtein distance by working through each position in the matrix. 
    # Working the columns
    for($columnIndex=1; $columnIndex -le $compareStringLength; $columnIndex++){
        # Cycle each character in the list
        $compareCharacter = $compareString[$columnIndex-1]

        # Working the rows
        for($rowIndex=1; $rowIndex -le $differenceStringLength; $rowIndex++){
            # Cycle each character in the list
            $differenceCharacter = $differenceString[$rowIndex-1]

            Write-Verbose "Matrix location: [$rowIndex, $columnIndex]"
            Write-Verbose "Compare character: $compareCharacter - Difference character: $differenceCharacter"
            # Calculate the cost
            $cost=if($compareCharacter -ceq $differenceCharacter){0}else{1}
            Write-Verbose "Cost: $cost"

            # The cell immediately above plus 1
            $cellAbove = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1
            Write-Verbose "Cell Above: [$($rowIndex-1), $columnIndex] + 1 = $cellAbove"

            # The cell immediately to the left plus 1
            $cellLeft =  $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,($columnIndex-1)] + 1
            Write-Verbose "Cell Left: [$rowIndex,$($columnIndex-1)] + 1 = $cellLeft"

            # The cell diagonally above and to the left plus the cost
            $cellUpperLeft = $comparisonMatrix[($rowIndex-1),($columnIndex-1)] + $cost
            Write-Verbose "Cell Upper Left: [$($rowIndex-1),$($columnIndex-1)] + cost($cost) = $cellUpperLeft"

            # Select minumum of the of the last 3 cells calculations and assign it to the current matrix position.
            $comparisonMatrix[$rowIndex,$columnIndex] = $cellAbove,$cellLeft,$cellUpperLeft | Measure-Object -Minimum | select -ExpandProperty Minimum
        }
    }
    # The cacluated LD will now be in the bottom right of the matrix.
    return $comparisonMatrix[$differenceStringLength,$compareStringLength]
}
```

Please note **case sensitivity** of the above functions. For *case insensitive* Levenshtein Distance:

- **permanently**: change `-ceq` to `-eq` in their two occurrences, or
- **ad hoc**, in a particular case: use `.ToUpper()` or `.ToLower()` functions, e.g. as

```
Get-LevenshteinDistance -CompareString $strC.ToUpper() -DifferenceString $strD.ToUpper()
# or
Get-LevenshteinDistance -CompareString $strC.ToLower() -DifferenceString $strD.ToLower()
```